# How to stretch Image to fill the Label Width set in Background in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, uilabel

I have simple View based application. I had taken only `UILabel` on it.

Following is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
lblBack.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cn3.png"];
lblBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
lblBack.text = @"Hello World!!!...";

//    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
//    
//    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, lblBack.frame.size.width, lblBack.frame.size.height);
//    [imgView setFrame:rect];
//    NSLog(@"Rect : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
//    [img drawInRect:rect];
//    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
//    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
//    [lblBack addSubview:imgView];
```

Comments shows some of the things that i have tried. I am getting following output:

[image]

In this one image is repeated 3 times. But I want that image should be stretched to fill the Label width.

I have referred some of the previous links that shows me to add Image in background and use `clearColor` for `UILabel`. Also seen example of Adding custom view in Background. But all this I dont want to use unless I dont have other solutions...

I just want to perform all things on `UILabel` only.... no other control except `UIImage` or `UIImageView` i want to use..

Comment: your code seems to be fine: lblBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];// have you checked your label's frame..?

Comment: I have checked it... and it's width is 320..

Comment: @DShah, I hope my answer solves your problem.. If yes, please accept the answer.. Otherwise, make a comment...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dhiren try this code :

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cab.png"];
    CGSize imgSize = testLabel.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

I have tested this code.

Comment: can u tell why "newImage" UIImage object will work and "img" is not working?

Comment: so why you are not using the same UIImage pointer and making this overhead when you can just do it in single line? testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];

Comment: -imageNamed: returns an autoreleased image, which, will be autoreleased at some time in the future (the exact time is undefined).

Comment: this is not a reason to opt for your solution. anyways... as you cab see that UIColor is using UIImage to make a color, and hence the UIImage's object will be of no use after UIColor has created a color from image.

Answer (score 1):

Porting over Maulik's answer to Swift 2.2, you get the following code:

```
var img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "cabImage")!
var imgSize: CGSize = testLabel.frame.size

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgSize)

img.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, imgSize.width, imgSize.height))
var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

testLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)
```

Personally tested to be working!