# How to achieve background Image in UILabel as in pic?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, uilabel

How to achieve below effect??

I want that when my `UIImage` width is smaller then `UILabel` width then my image should be displayed only once as below.

I already have done some more work with `UILabel` and `UIImage`. Refer to my previous question : [How to stretch Image to fill the Label Width set in Background in UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634083/how-to-stretch-image-to-fill-the-label-width-set-in-background-in-uilabel).

But now i want some more fun with `UILabel`... :D

[image: UILabel with small Image than width repeats only once...]

**EDIT :**

```
SBLabel *lbl = [[SBLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 28)];
lbl.text = @"Hello World!!!...";
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cn3.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 28)];
imgView.image = img;
[lbl setNonRepeatingBackgroundImage:imgView];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];

[imgView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (image.size.width < label.size.width ||image.size.height < label.size.height )
{
//rect here is frame of image
   [img drawInRect:rect];
   label.backgroudColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the most straightforward solution would be to have your `UIImage` sit behind your `UILabel` and your `UILabel` has a transparent background color.

**Edit**

Assuming you're using ARC...

**SBLabel.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SBLabel : UILabel

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *nonRepeatingBackgroundImage;

@end
```

**SBLabel.m**

```
#import "SBLabel.h"

@implementation SBLabel

@synthesize nonRepeatingBackgroundImage;

- (void)setNonRepeatingBackgroundImage:(UIImageView *)aNonRepeatingBackgroundImage {
    nonRepeatingBackgroundImage = aNonRepeatingBackgroundImage;
    [self addSubview:aNonRepeatingBackgroundImage];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:aNonRepeatingBackgroundImage];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}

@end
```

You would need to call this setter method after you add the UILabel to the parent view. I have not tested but I believe it should work, might require some tweaks but hopefully it explains how to Subclass UILabel to make a custom enhancement such as this.

Comment: that could be the bad solution if i take it.... Because to have hundreds of UILabel then it would be difficult to handle all Labels and Images...  So I want Image as Background of UILabel....

Comment: I'd suggest subclassing UILabel to handle this type of background image if that is the case.

Comment: can you please help me for subclassing.?? or atleast describe the way how to achieve that??

Comment: Added an example of subclassing `UILabel` with what I think will work, might require some tweaking.

Comment: Please see my EDIT section... i have implemented this but not getting image in background...

Comment: Subviews are always in front of their parent view, so adding the UIImageView will hide the text of the UILabel, you can have a UIView with two subviews: UIImageView and UILabel instead

Answer (score 0):

A subclass of UILabel could look like this (without ARC)

**CustomLabel.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomLabel : UILabel {
    UIImage *mImage;
}
@property (retain) UIImage *image;
@end
```

**CustomLabel.m**

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel

- (void)dealloc {
    self.image = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [mImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (UIImage*)image {
    return mImage;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if(mImage)
        [mImage release];
    mImage = [image retain];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

**Usage**

```
yourCustomLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
```

Comment: I have tried this same thing... but not getting image in background.... From where should i call `drawRect` method??? How setImage will be called? you have given usage syntax but does not contain that...  I think something is still missing which i am not able to figure out... please help me to figure it out...

Comment: You don't call drawRect, the rendering system calls it after setNeedsDisplay is called (when setImage: is called). setImage is called here: `yourCustomLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];`

Comment: I have created an example project. And like commented every single line of it. [link](http://weezer.random-host.com/eternity/CustomLabelExample.zip)