# Setting stretched UIImage as background for UILabel using resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uilabel

I have a chat application and I want to implement the chat bubbles as the background for the `UILabel`. This is what I'm trying to implement:

[image]

I tried using :

```
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]; 
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, scale);
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

which results in the image being stretched equally like so:
[image]

So I tried using the `resizableImageWithCapInsets` and setting the image using `colorWithPatternImage`.

```
UIImage *newImage = [img resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];
cell.answer.backgroundColor = [UIColor newImage];
```

But all it does is repeat the images as the background like so:

[image]

How do I stretch only the middle part of the image?

Or is it not possible using a `UILabel`?

Comment: i have one demo for chat and very simple so give me your email id i will send that demo and check that demo .

Comment: I think stop messing around with backgroundColor and simply use UIImageView, which would have the same frame as a label (or a bit bigger on each side) and place it under the label. That way You also receive the possibility to have label offset from bubble sides.) If You actually do manage to place it as a background - You will never have the possibility to offset text from sides.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Do send it to me at unnikrishnan.anil@gmail.com

Comment: @GuntisTreulands I'll try using a UIImageView.

Comment: okay i will send now .

Comment: You can receive mail ???

Comment: Got it. thanks. I'll have a look.

Comment: check and say that demo is useful or not .

Comment: @Anil this demo is useful for you so please upvote my answer in below .thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using for purpose UIButton

Answer (score 2):

For chating using the custom classes of PTSMessagingCell Here you can customize your images and other controls.

Catch the sample code  [PTSMessagingCell-master](https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell/)

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UIImageView *balloonView;
UILabel *label;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;       

    balloonView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    balloonView.tag = 1;

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.tag = 2;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    UIView *message = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    message.tag = 0;
    [message addSubview:balloonView];
    [message addSubview:label];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:message];

    [balloonView release];
    [label release];
    [message release];
}
else
{
    balloonView = (UIImageView *)[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0] viewWithTag:1];
    label = (UILabel *)[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0] viewWithTag:2];
}

NSString *text = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0f, 480.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UIImage *balloon;

if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
{
    balloonView.frame = CGRectMake(320.0f - (size.width + 28.0f), 2.0f, size.width + 28.0f, size.height + 15.0f);
    balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(307.0f - (size.width + 5.0f), 8.0f, size.width + 5.0f, size.height);
}
else
{
    balloonView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 2.0, size.width + 28, size.height + 15);
    balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(16, 8, size.width + 5, size.height);
}

balloonView.image = balloon;
label.text = text;

return cell;
      }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *body = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [body sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size.height + 15;
}
```

i hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: That works perfectly. I saw this too. But I want to do it using Storyboards cause I need to add other things to the cell as well. Easier that way. Programatically its going to take time.

Answer (score 0):

variable newSize must be equal to size of label.

and replace this

```
cell.answer.backgroundColor = [UIColor newImage];
```

with

```
cell.answer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
```

Let me know if it works :)

Reference [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634083/how-to-stretch-image-to-fill-the-label-width-set-in-background-in-uilabel):

Comment: what is newSize? is it uilabel frame.size ?